# "Parameter is invalid" when creating a new bitmap pointing to a filepath

Tags: c#, windows, bitmap, desktop

I am facing this weird issue when i attempt to create a new bitmap image to pass into a method.
The exception happens when at

bitmap bm = new bitmap("images/cat.jpg");

I have tried using various images of all sizes to try and test if it is the file size problem, however turns out only 1 existing image in the project can work(which is a picture of a cat).

All other images return the error "Parameter is invalid".. I am tried rebuilding the project and allowing read permissions, but i still can't get it to work.

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
       at Image_Authentication_Final.RegistrationForm.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Acc\Desktop\Image Authentication Final\Image Authentication Final\RegistrationForm.cs:line 176
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Image_Authentication_Final.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Acc\Desktop\Image Authentication Final\Image Authentication Final\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Possibly the same?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099246/system-drawing-parameter-is-not-valid

Comment: @dbc Just tried it, does not work at all...

Comment: Just tried using the exact same image, copying it and renaming the second copy to cat2.jpg.. and if i put that image into the bitmap it returns me the error, what the?!

Comment: Is this `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("images/cat.jpg");` all you're doing to create a bitmap or are you using another parameters that you didn't show?

Comment: Would it be possible that you upload one of the images that don't work in a zip to sendspace or something?

Comment: @t3chb0t basically the lines after this performs data hiding using steganography. This is the first line once the user clicks a button.

Comment: @t3chb0t i'll upload it to imgur but i'm outside now, once i get home i'll post bsck to this thread..

Comment: It would be better if you uploaded it as a zip because I think it might get modified on image hosting pages.

Comment: @t3chb0t sure, will post in an hour or so. Thanks again! :)

Comment: The image that causes the exception, is it an original image or after you modified it with your steganography algorithm because then your algorithm might be broken and damage the image. Can you open it in any picture viewer at all?

Comment: @t3chb0t the images are clean images that i downloaded off the net. At first i discovered it might be because of the image size (as mentioned in another thread) however i realized finding a smaller image didn't work either. I am more interested as to why a 1.5mb picture of a cat works, but not any images smaller, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try a fully qualified path to the image file with double backslashes ("C:\test\abc.jpg")
- Determine if the jpeg file is valid for .net's image codec

  - Create jpeg in MS Paint
  - Create jpeg in Gimp, Photoshop, ...
  - Use imagemagick to convert the jpeg from jpeg to png and then back to jpeg
  - Use jpegtran to optimize the jpeg to force rewriting of the jpeg header
- Use imagemagick's identify or gimp to determine what is in the jpeg (it could be a different image file format or jpeg 2000)
- In .net code, use File or FileInfo calls to verify that the file exists, has non-zero length and is acessible

If the file is on a network drive and has just been written, it may take a second or two for the file to be released from exclusive use even after the file has been closed by the creator of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your input, fortunately imagemagick is an existing library in my project and i actually tried grabbing the image info (without actually converting it) and still no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add.  .NET is notoriously odd at handling bitmaps and images and needs image resources to be freed up or disposed.  Repeatedly doing image operations without freeing them will cause issues.

Check the handles count of the process in process explorer.

For server-side or even desktop applications for image processing, I've written the image to disk, then ran imagemagick.exe  command line to process the image and waited for the image file output to be written.  It allows imagemagick to start, do image operation, and exit all in one process without clogging up .net's memory or handles.